# How can I find the mistake in ASP.net SQL insert query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

hello iam making insert in a table using asp.net this my code below  ,i got this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'  can any body help me to figure out the problem

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-U11A4VS6;Initial Catalog=Task;Integrated Security=True");
           con.Open();
           //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Invoice_Product", con);
           //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Invoice_Product] (" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInvoice.Text)
             + "','"+Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInvoice.Text)+"','"+"'"+TextBoxDate.Text+"'"
             + "','"+"'"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+"'"
             +"','"+"'"+DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text+"'"+"','"+Convert.ToDouble(LabelPrice1.Text) 
             + "','"+Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxQty.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToDouble(LabelTot1.Text)
             + "','"+Convert.ToDouble(LabelDiscount1.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToDouble(LabelNet1.Text)  
             + "','"+"'"+DropDownListStores.SelectedItem.Text+"'"+"','"+Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxFinalTot.Text)
             + "','"+Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxTaxes.Text)+ "','"+Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxFinalNet.Text)+")",con);

           int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (k > 0)
           {
                Response.Write("<script> alert ('User Added')</Script>)");

           }
           else Response.Write("<script> alert ('Error')</Script>)");

           //con.Close();
       }
```

Comment: Oh God no... **Don't** build queries like this... **EVER**.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: could you please help me with the right way ?

Comment: [Use parameterised queries to avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities](https://bobby-tables.com/) (it also ends up with much more legible, maintainable code, which is always nice)

Comment: Here's a simple example for parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

First of all, learn how to use parameter binding in inserts. You are SQL Injection exposed.

First achievement to find the error in syntax is to put the query in a string variable and stop the debugger right before execute statement.

You'll can copy and paste in SQL client.

A first approach of rewriting your code. Missing some columns, only for your guidance. Check the link at the bottom.

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-U11A4VS6;Initial Catalog=Task;Integrated Security=True");

       con.Open();
       //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Invoice_Product", con);
       //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       string sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Invoice_Product] VALUES (@FIELD1, @FIELD2)"

       //put the breakpoint on next line and check the value of sqlString
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString,con);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIELD1", SqlDbType.Int);
       cmd.Parameters["@FIELD1"].Value = TextBoxInvoice.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIELD2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
       cmd.Parameters["@FIELD2"].Value = TextBoxDate.Text;

       int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       if (k > 0)
       {
            Response.Write("<script> alert ('User Added')</Script>)");
       }
       else 
           Response.Write("<script> alert ('Error')</Script>)");

       //con.Close();
   }
```

Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: As you say yourself - one should ***NEVER EVER*** write SQL code like that - so please don't write up solutions that "recommend" that way! If anything - show how to use **parametrized queries** properly!

Comment: edited with bind params, not tested

Answer (score 0):

You have things like this in your code:

```
"','"+"'"
```

which will output:

```
',''
```

so you're doubling up your quote marks in some places.

---

I'd pay attention to the above comment though, this really isn't a good way to build queries.

Comment: But **REALLY**, one should ***NEVER EVER*** write SQL code like that - period.

Comment: This is a really off-brand band-aid over a gushing wound...

Comment: FYI - I'm not advocating the method being used, but that's not what the question is asking.

Comment: @marc_s I agree, but there's no SQL in my answer - and I'm not advocating the use of that string concatenation, so don't really think the downvote is necessary here. I _get it_ - but I don't agree with it in a pure Q&A bubble.

Comment: @Sam: it wasn't **me** who downvoted you - so I can't really "undo" that - sorry

Comment: @marc_s no worries, appreciate the reply in any case.